# "Remember me" feature based on ip address

Tags: security, authentication, remember-me

I'm new to user authentication and related digital security issues, so I would like to know if the way I'm doing things is ok. Currently the way my server "remembers" users is based solely on the IP address they have logged in from. If they check the remember me option, I store that IP in the database and from then on, every time that machine enters the website, I check if that IP is associated with one of my users. If so, I log them in.

What is good or bad on that approach?

Comment: What if a user has a dynamic IP address?  Or if multiple users share the same IP address?  You're essentially logging someone in without validating that they are who you assume they are.

Comment: This is a really bad idea. Whole organizations (companies, sometimes ISPs) have the same external IP.